# Store multiple JSON object values in PHP variable

Tags: php, json, object

I'm trying to store multiple json values for a single object in a php variable but so far have been unsuccessful. When I try the code below it stores the last value for the object but not both.

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

foreach($_POST->repliesCounts as $replies_counts)
{
$replies_counts_userid = $replies_counts->userId . " | ";
$replies_counts_repliescount = $replies_counts->repliesCount . " | ";
}
```

Here is the JSON string:

```
 "repliesCounts": 
  [
    {
        "userId": 789,
        "repliesCount": 4
    },
    {
        "userId": 111,
        "repliesCount": 3
    }
  ]
```

My question is, how can I store both sets of values in a single variable? Preferably separated by a | symbol or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$replies_counts_userid = $replies_counts->userId . " | ";`

This line completely replaces the old value with a new one. You need to concatenate here as well:

`$replies_counts_userid .= $replies_counts->userId . " | ";`

Should work. (Notice the `.` before the `=`)

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to declare those variables outside the `foreach` loop, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Completely forgot about the . concat operator

Answer (score 3):

You can `json_decode` with the second parameter as `true` to return an associative array instead of an object. Use `array_column` to extract a column from the array and convert it into a simple array. Use `implode` to join the simple arrays.

```
$str = '{"repliesCounts": [{ "userId": 789,"repliesCount": 4},{"userId": 111,"repliesCount": 3}]}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

//Make associative array into a simple array
$replies_counts_userid = array_column( $arr['repliesCounts'], 'userId' );
$replies_counts_repliescount = array_column( $arr['repliesCounts'], 'repliesCount' );

//implode array
$replies_counts_userid = implode(' | ', $replies_counts_userid);
$replies_counts_repliescount = implode(' | ', $replies_counts_repliescount);
```

This will result to

```
$replies_counts_userid = '789 | 111';
$replies_counts_repliescount = '4 | 3';
```

Comment: Just a note, `array_column` works on arrays of objects as well in PHP 7.

Comment: I didn't know that. We learn something new everyday. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for that, I went with the other answer since the rest of the json string is already coded as objects but this is useful info to have